# Issuing centering dynamically sized object with JavaScript in Prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, prototypejs

I've got an edge to edge video that resizes to the browser dynamically, would like to center it on the page now. Because the video's size varies, I need to do this with JavaScript.

You lovely folks helped me with correct syntax which was a major issue I had, but I'm still not seeing the results I'm looking for.

The theory is that the function measures the browser viewports width and height and the video's width and height, subtracts the video from the browser, then divides that by two and applies it as `left` and `top` values in CSS. The video is set to `position:absolute` is in a div that's set to `position:fixed`.

UPDATE:

With @Guffa's advice in mind, I defined the video as a variable and applied the styles to it directly. The code is sound and shows no errors, but I'm not seeing the result. Honestly.. Been trying at this for a few days and can't figure it out.

UPDATE:

Tested the code by commenting out lines 4 and 5 below and adding in `vid.style.left = (500) + "px";` and that WORKED.. also tested with `vid.style.left = (windowWidth) + "px";` and that WORKED... which means the code is failing at `parseInt(vid.style.width,10)`. The logic of that line is to calculate the video's existing width... What's the issue?

Test page: http://kzmnt.com/test/

Lines 55 through 59 are in question (reformatted for reading ease):

```
var windowWidth = document.viewport.getWidth();
var windowHeight =  document.viewport.getHeight();
var vid = document.getElementById('live');
vid.style.left = ((windowWidth - parseInt(vid.style.width,10)) / 2) + "px";
vid.style.top = ((windowHeight - parseInt(vid.style.height,10)) / 2) + "px";
```

Ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not just set its width to 100%, and absolutely position it? Also, almost everything, including getting and setting properties is easier with jquery (even if jquery is not necessary for the task).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var windowWidth = document.viewport.getWidth();
var windowHeight =  document.viewport.getHeight();
var vid = document.getElementById('live');
vid.style.left = ((windowWidth - (vid.width)) / 2) + "px";
vid.style.top = ((windowHeight - (vid.height)) / 2) + "px";
```

Answer (score 3):

The error that you get is from the mismatching parentheses.

Just adding some parentheses won't make the code work, though. The code is dividing the element with by two and then subtracting that from the window width, which will place the element halfway outside the window.

You should first subtract the element width from the window width, then divide by two:

```
this.style.left = ((windowWidth - parseInt(this.style.width,10)) / 2) + "px";
this.style.top = ((windowHeight - parseInt(this.style.height,10)) / 2) + "px";
```

#### Edit:

As the width and height styles are not set on the video element, you have to pick up the size that is calculated for it. It's put in the width and height HTML properties, so you can get those values and parse them.

```
element.style.left = ((windowWidth - parseInt(element.width)) / 2) + "px";
element.style.top = ((windowHeight - parseInt(element.height)) / 2) + "px";
```

Comment: LOL, I didn't even *look* at the actual calculation. +1

Comment: @Guffa - Your code is clearly superior... Thanks for the clarification. The video's still not centering- updated my code and edited the question to explain. Can you take a look?

Comment: @technopeasant: The main reason that nothing changes is that you have put that code after the `return` statement in a function, so it's never executed.

Comment: @Guffa - Egg on my face! That's what I get for hastily building it into the getVideoDimensions function. I really appreciate your help and patience. I decided that getVideoDimensions was a good place for it because the centering needs to be calculated whenever the video's resized. It seems that it's not the right home for it above the return because the adjusted width and height are part of the calculations. What do you think? Also getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined" which I understand to be as "this" is undefined..

Comment: @technopeasant: The size of the video is specified as 1280x720 in the code, and then the code calculates the size of the video to fit the screen. If you want to center it, you only have to set the width or the height depending on the dimensions, not both. The value of `this` is never `undefined`. In this case its the videoplayer object. You would have to get a reference to the containing element for the video, so set it's position. You would have to use the calculated size, not the current size of the element, as the method only calculates the size so it's not set yet.

Comment: @Guffa - Okay, I think I understand what you're saying. I reapproached it, this time defining the video tag as a variable and applying the styles to it.. but still no luck. Video isn't centered and getting an error. Updating my question with the details. If you're still available, I'd appreciate your help. Thank you  so much.

Comment: @technopeasant: The `getElementsByTagName` method returns an array, in this case containing one element. You can't apply the style to the array, you have to get the element from the array and apply the style to it: `vid[0].style...`.

Comment: @Guffa - Ah, makes sense. Would I then replace all of the vid variables with vid[0], indicating that it's the first video element in the array?

Comment: @technopeasant: Yes, or get the first element and put in the variable.

Comment: @Guffa - Added an ID to the video, defined it as the variable, and applied your code. No go. Absolutely awe-struck. Updated http://kzmnt.com/test/ with the new code. What am I missing?

Comment: @technopeasant: You are still getting the width and height from the width and height style of the element, but there is no initial style for those. You need to use the size that you calculate in `getVideoDimensions`.

Comment: @Guffa - got it!!!!!!... ((windowWidth - (vid.width)) / 2) + "px"; updated kzmnt.com/test with it- the centering is working beautifully. not quite your answer.. please update your answer with the working code. you deserve the credit for the question. I can't thank you enough for your guidance, patience, and knowledge. Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: @technopeasant let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1136/discussion-between-guffa-and-technopeasant)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the JavaScript error is that you have mismatched parentheses.

```
//                                           add paren here ------------v
this.style.left = (windowWidth  - (parseInt(this.style.width,10)  / 2  )) + 'px';
//                                                and here ------------v
this.style.top  = (windowHeight - (parseInt(this.style.height,10) / 2 )) + 'px';
```

(Also note [Guffa's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561918/issue-centering-dynamically-sized-object-with-native-javascript/6561973#6561973) about the calculation being slightly off.)

---

**Off-topic**: It looks as though your element is using absolute positioning and has a specific width. If so, I'm not immediately seeing why you need JavaScript to do the positioning at all; you may be better off with CSS: You set the `left` to "50%", and then set your `margin-left` to be half of the width of the element. E.g.:

```
#yourElementId {
    position:    absolute;
    width:       500px;  /* Or whatever */
    left:        50%;
    margin-left: -250px; /* Half of `width` above */
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/odehom)

I believe it works when the width / height are percentages, too ([seems to](http://jsbin.com/odehom/3)), but I'm no CSS guru...

Comment: Crowder - I've used CSS centering often, but the video dynamically resizes to match the browser window's size.. so no go.

Comment: @techno: Gotcha. Then the parens (and Guffa's point about the logic) should sort things out.

Answer (score 0):

On both lines, you have 3 opening brackets, but only 2 closing brackets.